# Encoding 4k in HM hevc reference software

Tags: video, video-processing, video-encoding, hevc

I am having trouble encoding 4k 3840x2160 video using the HEVC-HM[16.18],
it works fine with the HD 1920x1080 and lower resolusions but in case of high resolutions it encodes only one GOP (16 frames) and it crashs , I thought it was because the small RAM I have (8Go) but it seems consuming only 30% so could it be a compiling/configuration problem?
I am using CPU of 20 cores 2.4 GHz & 8G of RAM 
and the regulaire random access configuration for the encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a 64-bit binary? 32-bit binaries are only able to use up to 2 GB of RAM. In the Visual Studio work spaces unfortunately 32-bit is the default.

Maybe also try runing the software in a debugger, to check at what kind of operation it crashes, e.g. check if it's a memory allocation.

Comment: Thanks a lot , yeah that was the problem ; i recompile it with the 64 bit setting in VS and it works fine now.